# Как создать поток который бы не влиял на основной?

Tags: android

У меня есть 2 кнопки в программе. Пауза и Старт. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было по кнопке pause остановить некий поток. допустим

Thread. А по кнопке Старт продолжить поток.

Но так чтобы основной поток не завис.

Если Thread для этой операции не подходит. То что тогда мне использовать?

Comment: Вы бы описали задачу которую решить пытаетесь, а не способ на потоках. Ибо что то странное вы с потоками делаете. При запуске нового потока никакие другие потоки не зависают, если в них принудительно не запустить ожидание чего то из нового потока.

Comment: @xkor. Есть некая функция. это функция запускается каждые 10 сек. Нужно взаимодействовать кнопки старт и пауза.

Если я нажал старт. и на оставшеейся 8 сек. я нажал пауза. А спустя час нажму опять на кнопку Старт то через 2 сек. должна запустться это функция...

Comment: @xTIGRx а пробовали сделать на основе handler функцию, которая будет поддерживать оставшееся время, если нажать пауза, то ничего не делать.

Comment: @pavel, неа. Я даже незнаю как. А использовать TimerTask не получится? ну так чтобы пауза работала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте это реализовать с помощью бэкграунд службы, примеров по этой теме достаточно. Для начала посмотрите [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/run-background-service/create-service.html). Ваш бэкграунд будет отправлять, когда нужно оповещение в основное активити(моделируется стоп) и vice versa! Еще как вариант можно попробовать использовать ScheduledExecutorService, но там нужно указать интервал повторения задачи.